# Почему цикл for не работает?

Tags: python, for

Я совсем новичок в python, и совсем не понимаю, как работает цикл `for`. Учусь по книге "Изучаем python" Эрика Мэтиза.
Вот код

```
i = ['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e']
for i in letters:
    print(letters + ' this is letter')
```

В книге код работает

```
magicians = ['alice', 'david', 'carolina']
for magician in magicians:
    print(magician.title() + ", that was a great trick!")
```

Comment: print(i + ' this is letter')  надо бы наверное?

Comment: `for i in letters` - ничего не путаете? ;-)

Comment: Ничего не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементы списка перечисляются через запятую.
Имя списка - `letters`.
Печатать элементы списка используя переменную цикла `i`, которая на каждой итерации цикла принимает очередное значение из списка `letters`.
*(В общем, вы перепутали места `i` и `letters`)*

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in letters:
    print(i + ' this is letter')
```

Comment: Теперь сработало

Comment: @lemoname, если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Я знаю просто его нужно принять минимум черз 5 минут "Вы можете принять ответ через 5 минут" когда пытаюсь принять ответ